# mysql 8.0 replication io_thread cannot keep up

Tags: mysql, replication, master

We have created a new MySQL 8.0 cluster. 
Our servers are running ubuntu 18.04.
We are running `percona-server-server 8.0.18-9-1.bionic amd64`.

However, we have issues that the slave cannot keep up (io_thread) with the master.

Our new cluster contains of a master and a slave.

The servers have the following specs:
https://www.hetzner.com/dedicated-rootserver/ex52

Sysctl settings: https://pastebin.com/wuZZAWqW

MySQL Slave server variables: https://pastebin.com/0tJcCnbR

If we test a network connection, it reaches 1 Gbps. So network should not be an issue.

Writing to disk and reading from disk (nvme ssd) is super fast. When we test with dd we reach speeds over 1Gbps.

CPU is low. IO wait is low. Still, our slave cannot keep up with our master.

Example:
We import a fresh timezone data into our master:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql mysql
```

Executing this command takes **1,6 second** (which loads +/- 150k lines outputted by the mysql_tzinfo_to_sql command.)

However, if we check our slave, it just keeps loading and loading... it seems that somehow the io_thread has troubles retrieving the binlog data from the master. The data comes in, but way too  slow.

The sql thread of the slave can keep up. So this is not the issue. We even tried to set up multiple workers using the `slave_parallel_workers` variable, but this made no difference.

Master status before importing the tz database:

```
mysql> show master status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             File: mysql-bin.000007
         Position: 11732690
     Binlog_Do_DB: 
 Binlog_Ignore_DB: 
Executed_Gtid_Set: 4c16dd91-62ac-11ea-bacb-96000043b9a4:1-460
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Slave status before importing the tz database:

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: xxx
                  Master_User: replicator
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000007
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 11732690
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 11732864
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000007
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 11732690
              Relay_Log_Space: 11733068
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1337
                  Master_UUID: 4c16dd91-62ac-11ea-bacb-96000043b9a4
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 4c16dd91-62ac-11ea-bacb-96000043b9a4:451-460
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 4c16dd91-62ac-11ea-bacb-96000043b9a4:1-460
                Auto_Position: 1
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
       Master_public_key_path: 
        Get_master_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, the slave is now in sync with the master (`Read_Master_Log_Pos` on the slave is the same as the `Position` on the master)

**After importing the tz database on the master:**

Master status

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             File: mysql-bin.000007
         Position: 17598938
     Binlog_Do_DB: 
 Binlog_Ignore_DB: 
Executed_Gtid_Set: 4c16dd91-62ac-11ea-bacb-96000043b9a4:1-465
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Slave status:

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Queueing master event to the relay log
                  Master_Host: xxx
                  Master_User: replicator
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000007
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 12077595
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 11733556
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000007
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 11733382
              Relay_Log_Space: 12077973
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1337
                  Master_UUID: 4c16dd91-62ac-11ea-bacb-96000043b9a4
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 4c16dd91-62ac-11ea-bacb-96000043b9a4:451-464
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 4c16dd91-62ac-11ea-bacb-96000043b9a4:1-464
                Auto_Position: 1
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
       Master_public_key_path: 
        Get_master_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see in the `Read_Master_Log_Pos` variable, the slave is just behind.

It took the slave **1 minute and 28 seconds** to execute the same commands!!!

We see that the following is happening:

1. Master executes commands (very fast)
2. Slave reads the binlog (`Read_Master_Log_Pos` is increasing very slowly). Glances shows us that the network throughput is +/- 600kbps
3. When `Read_Master_Log_Pos` is the same as the masters `Position`, the `Relay_Log_Pos` on the slave increases.
4. The Slave's CPU jumps to 100% for a second or so
5. The Slave now contains the same data as the master.

We have double checked, but there is no issue with our disk i/o speed (on neither master or slave). We tried to enable data compression, but it makes no difference. Once again we tested our network speed, and it is just super fast.

We have inspected the binlogs with a command like:

```
mysqlbinlog --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS -v mysql-bin.000007 | more
```

We do not see anything strange in the bin logs.

We tried various settings like:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout=1800
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit= 0
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_io_capacity=2000
...
```

It made no difference. Does anybody have any clue how we could solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally we found the issue. The setting `sync_relay_log=1` was the problem. After disabling this option it is super fast.

We are now working through this information about how we can configure our server the best in case of unexpected problems:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-solutions-unexpected-slave-halt.html